# Rational slice knot that is not slice

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, knot-theory, 4-manifolds

Does there exists a knot $K\subset \mathbb{S}^3$ such that

1. $K$ is **not** slice
2. $\exists W^4$, $\partial W = \mathbb{S}^3$ *rational homology ball*
3. $\exists $ properly embedded smooth disk $(D,\partial D)\to (W,K)$. ?

In other words $K$ is not slice in $B^4$ but is slice in some rational homology ball.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. The figure-eight knot is an example: it bounds a smooth slice disk in a rational homology ball. This has been proven in a bunch of different ways, going back to the 1980s. Here are a couple of relevant references:

*Fintushel, Ronald; Stern, Ronald J.*, A (\mu)-invariant one homology 3-sphere that bounds an orientable rational ball, Four-manifold theory, Proc. AMS-IMS-SIAM Joint Summer Res. Conf., Durham/N.H. 1982, Contemp. Math. 35, 265-268 (1984). [ZBL0566.57006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0566.57006).

*Cha, Jae Choon*, [**The structure of the rational concordance group of knots**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/memo/0885), Mem. Am. Math. Soc. 885, 95 p. (2007). [ZBL1130.57034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1130.57034).

*Akbulut, Selman; Larson, Kyle*, [**Brieskorn spheres bounding rational balls**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/proc/13828), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 146, No. 4, 1817-1824 (2018). [ZBL1422.57081](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1422.57081).

However, it remains unknown whether there's a knot is slice in an integer homology ball but not in $B^4$.

Answer (score 3):

Rationally slice knots in $S^3$ are in abundance due to the collection of Kawauchi's theorems and the recent result of Kim and Wu:

**Theorem ([1] + [2]):** Any hyperbolic amphicheiral knot $K$ in $S^3$ is rationally slice.

**Theorem ([3]):** Any fibered, negative amphicheiral knot $K$ in $S^3$ with irreducible Alexander polynomial (called *Miyazaki knot*) is rationally slice.

Using these theorems, you may find plenty of rationally slice knots that are not smoothly slice.

**[1]:** Kawauchi, Akio. "The invertibility problem on amphicheiral excellent knots." *Proceedings of the Japan Academy, Series A, Mathematical Sciences* 55.10 (1979): 399-402.

**[2]:** Kawauchi, Akio. "Rational-slice knots via strongly negative-amphicheiral knots." *Commun. Math. Res.* 25.2 (2009): 177-192.

**[3]:** Kim, Min Hoon, and Zhongtao Wu. "On rational sliceness of Miyazaki's fibered,− amphicheiral knots." *Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society* 50.3 (2018): 462-476.